# Not a mathematical equation to solve

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

If

**R + G = Y**,

**B + R = M** and

**G + B = C**

then, what is the value of **R + B + G** ?

Well, it is *NOT* (Y+M+C) / 2 !

Comment: Kind of obvious...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this really just

> the [colour wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_wheel)?
>
>  [image: image of colour wheel]

**R + G = Y**

> Red and green make yellow.

**B + R = M**

> Blue and red make magenta.

**G + B = C**

> Green and blue make cyan.

*then, what is the value of R + B + G?*

> Red and blue and green (the primary colours of light) make **white**.

*Well, it is NOT (Y+M+C) / 2 !*

> Because yellow and magenta and cyan (the primary colours of ink) make *black*.

Comment: Yes @Rand al'Thor, you got it correct. So provide the required letter in your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer should be

> W, since R,G & B represent primary colours and Y,M & C are intermediate colours. R+G+B combined make white, thus W.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  How does your answer add to the identical ones already given? You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.

Comment: There is no answer that spesifically says letter 'W'.